# Progress Bar on loading Images in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, progress-bar

I want to know the code to add Progress Bar before the Images are loaded in my RecyclerView. Here is my RecyclerViewAdapter Code.

RecyclerViewAdapter.java

```
package com.example.rizkafs.laundrize;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<DataLaundry> rvData;
    private Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(List<DataLaundry> rvData) {
        this.rvData = rvData;
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // di tutorial ini kita hanya menggunakan data String untuk tiap item
        CardView cv;
        public TextView nama;
        public TextView alamat;
        public TextView jenis;
        public ImageView imageVIew;
        public ProgressBar progress;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            cv = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            nama = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_judul);
            alamat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.alamat);
            jenis = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.jenis);
            imageVIew = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            progress = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progress);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // membuat view baru
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.laundry_card, parent, false);
        // mengeset ukuran view, margin, padding, dan parameter layout lainnya
        context = parent.getContext();
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int i) {
        try {
            // - mengambil elemen dari dataset (ArrayList) pada posisi tertentu
            // - mengeset isi view dengan elemen dari dataset tersebut
            DataLaundry list = rvData.get(i);
            holder.nama.setText(list.getNama());
            holder.alamat.setText(list.getAlamat());
            holder.jenis.setText(list.getJenis());
            Log.d("GetData", list.getHarga());
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://laundrize-68cee.appspot.com/");
            StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child(list.getImage_url().get(0));
            Glide.with(context)
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(pathReference)
                    .into(holder.imageVIew);
            holder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.cv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("dataLaundry", rvData.get(i));
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

laundry_card.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/card_view"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="11dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="11dp">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="170dp"
                    android:id="@+id/gambar">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"/>
                    <ProgressBar
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/progress"/>

                 </RelativeLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_judul"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/gambar"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Judul"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/alamat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/txt_judul"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Alamat"/>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/jenis"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/alamat"
                    android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:text="Jenis"/>

            </RelativeLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

I already add the Progress Bar but it doesn't work, there is just a blank space before the images are loaded. I've delete the import code above to minimize the code that are show in here. Thank you, sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Can you show codes for your layout `laundry_card`?

Comment: i've edited the post above

Comment: Don't use ProgressBar. Glide should have a method to set some drawable at loading time - placeholder , you may use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try my codes, need to set `Visible` for progress bar before you load image by Glide to see your progressbar :

```
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Glide.with(context)
                .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                .load(pathReference)

     .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
         @Override
         public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
             return false;
         }

         @Override
         public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
             progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             return false;
         }
     })
     .into(holder.imageVIew)
;
```

Comment: i've got error in progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE), i've tried to change it to holder.progress.setVisibility(View.GONE) but it said the holder must be declared as final. Then i tried to apply it and then error again in RequestListener